# one event triggers multiple AJAX request

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, html

```
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var finishedCount = 0; //Count the amount of completed Ajax requests
         var data; //Keep track of the first request's data
         var data1; //Keep track of the second request's data
         function finished(){
             finishedCount++;
             if (finishedCount >= 2){ //2 is the amount of requests
                 //Do what you need done using data and data1
                             $(document).on('mouseenter','.grid-item',function(){
                                 var container = $(this);
                                 container.find('.title-wrap').html('<p class="job-name">'+ data +'</p>');
                                 container.find('.title-wrap').html('<p class="client-name">'+ data1 +'</p>');
                                 console.log(data);
                             });

             };
         };

            $(document).on('mouseenter','.grid-item',function(){
                 var container = $(this);
                 var jobId = container.children().find('.title-wrap-hidden').text();

         $.ajax({
             url: 'db_job_name_lookup.php',
             type: 'POST',
             data: {jobId: jobId},
             success: function(data) {
                 // success
                 data = data;
                 finished();
                                //  console.log(data);
             },
             error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
                 // error
                 alert(errorThrown);
             }
         });


          $.ajax({
             url: 'db_client_name_lookup.php',
             type: 'POST',
             data: {jobId: jobId},
             success: function(data1) {
                 // success
                 data1 = data1;
                 finished();
                                //  console.log(data1);
             },
             error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
                 // error
                 alert(errorThrown);
             }
         });
         });



                $(document).on('mouseleave', '.grid-item', function(){

              var container = $(this);
              container.find('.title-wrap').html('<p class="job-name"></p>');
              container.find('.title-wrap').html('<p class="client-name"></p>');

        });
    });




    </script>
```

Hi everyone, I want to use one event to make multiple AJAX request and I want to have both response result available to use at the same time. I tried using the above code, but it only gives back one response at a time and it even looks confused as to which result it should give, I tried using $.when and $.then but I pretty sure I'm not using it right. How would I accomplish this task?

PAGE 1

```
    <?php
require_once("../includes/site_init.php");


if(isset($_POST['jobId']) && $_POST['jobId'] !==NULL && $_POST['jobId'] !==0){
  $job_id = $_POST['jobId'];

  $portfolio_item_client = JobClient::find_by_sql('SELECT client_id FROM '.'job_client'." WHERE job_id = '" . $job_id . "' ");
  $client_name = Client::find_by_sql('SELECT name FROM '.'client'." WHERE id = '" .$portfolio_item_client[0]->client_id."'");
  echo $client_name[0]->name;
}else {
  echo 'result failed';
}
?>
```

PAGE 2

```
    <?php
require_once("../includes/site_init.php");


if(isset($_POST['jobId']) && $_POST['jobId'] !==NULL && $_POST['jobId'] !==0){
  $job_id = $_POST['jobId'];

  $portfolio_item_name = Job::find_by_sql('SELECT name FROM '.'job'." WHERE id = '" . $job_id . "' LIMIT 1");
  echo $portfolio_item_name[0]->name;
}else {
  echo 'result failed';
}
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `$.when` to resolve the promises

```
 $(document).on('mouseenter', '.grid-item', function() {
 var container = $(this);
 var jobId = container.children().find('.title-wrap-hidden').text();

 var ajax = $.ajax({
   url: 'db_job_name_lookup.php',
   type: 'POST',
   data: {
     jobId: jobId
   },
   success: function(data) {
     // success
     data = data;
   },
   error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
     // error
     alert(errorThrown);
   }
 });


 var ajax1 = $.ajax({
   url: 'db_client_name_lookup.php',
   type: 'POST',
   data: {
     jobId: jobId
   },
   success: function(data1) {
     // success
     data1 = data1;
   },
   error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
     // error
     alert(errorThrown);
   }
 });

 var container = $(this);
 $.when(ajax, ajax1).done(function(data, data1) {
   container.find('.title-wrap').html('<p class="job-name">'+ data +'</p>');
   container.find('.title-wrap').html('<p class="client-name">'+ data1 +'</p>');
 });


 });
 });
```

if you want to do a single ajax call you do the following: single_page.php

```
    <?php
require_once("../includes/site_init.php");

header('Content-Type: application/json');
if(isset($_POST['jobId']) && $_POST['jobId'] !==NULL && $_POST['jobId'] !==0){
  $job_id = $_POST['jobId'];

  $portfolio_item_client = JobClient::find_by_sql('SELECT client_id FROM '.'job_client'." WHERE job_id = '" . $job_id . "' ");
  $client_name = Client::find_by_sql('SELECT name FROM '.'client'." WHERE id = '" .$portfolio_item_client[0]->client_id."'");
  $data['client_name']=$client_name[0]->name;

  $portfolio_item_name = Job::find_by_sql('SELECT name FROM '.'job'." WHERE id = '" . $job_id . "' LIMIT 1");
  $data['portfolio_item_name']=$portfolio_item_name[0]->name;
echo json_encode(array('result'=>$data))
}else {
echo json_encode(array('result'=>'result failed'))
}
?>
```

js:

```
 $(document).on('mouseenter', '.grid-item', function() {
     var container = $(this);
$.ajax({
       url: 'single_page.php',
       type: 'POST',
       data: {
         jobId: jobId
       },
       success: function(data) {
         container.find('.title-wrap').html('<p class="job-name">'+ data.result.portfolio_item_name  +'</p>');
       container.find('.title-wrap').html('<p class="client-name">'+ data.result.client_name  +'</p>');
       },
       error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
         // error
         alert(errorThrown);
       }
     });
 });
```

Comment: thanks for response, I tried your method, I only get one at a time. What am I messing up?

Comment: what do you mean one at a time, how do you know that,why do you want both at the same time, why don't you use a single ajax call?

Comment: Oh it works now I was messing up in the HTML, sweet thanks, well I'm getting two sets of data from the database, A job name and a the name of the client the job belongs to, and when I hover over the job (an image) I want to display both job name and client name, so I figured I needed two AJAX request to get this data. If there is a better way to do it please let me know. Thanks again.

Comment: you can use a single ajax call and get both the job name and the client name,you will have less server requests

Comment: How would use a single AJAX request to 2 different urls, what would that look like in code? and the returned data would be an array or object? thanks.

Comment: you will need to combine the 2 pages into one page

Comment: I edit the code above to show what my 2 php scripts look like, what would be your advice for combining those and returning the data to AJAX, then how would I access this multi data in AJAX?

Comment: cool thanks very much, out of curiosity though, if I'm using the json file, let say I add a new item to the database, does the json file update automatically and does the AJAX automatically call that updated json file?

Comment: on mouseenter it automatically queries the db and forms the json string

Comment: hello again in the php when you take $data and say array('result'=>$data); what going on there, whats the logic behind that?

Comment: you can remove that array, i usually do it that way to pass the error messages you can simply do json_encode($data) and in the js you remove the result property from the append function

Comment: lol yeh ran some test and I understand it now, my first time using json. Thanks again though.

Answer (score 2):

Lets make an analogy. An Ajax request is like sending somebody to the store, and when they get back, they will do what you tell them. What you are trying to do is send two people to the store separately, and force them both to return at the same time. That won't work.

What you can do is keep track of which has returned, and whenever one comes back, check if they are both back. If they are, then you can tell them what to do at once (call a function). Or, you can have one go to the store, and when they return, they can tell the other one to go to the store, and when the second one returns, then tell them what to do (call a function).

Bottom line: you can't force them to finish at the same time, but you can wait until they are both done to run `container.find('....`

EDIT: Assuming all you need is to execute code once both requests are done, I would do this:

```
    var finishedCount = 0; //Count the amount of completed Ajax requests
    var data; //Keep track of the first request's data
    var data1; //Keep track of the second request's data
    function finished(){
        finishedCount++;
        if (finishedCount >= 2){ //2 is the amount of requests
            //Do what you need done using data and data1
        }
    }
    $.ajax({
        url: 'db_job_name_lookup.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {jobId: jobId},
        success: function(data) {
            data = data;
            finished();
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
            alert(errorThrown);
        }
    });

    $.ajax({
        url: 'db_client_name_lookup.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {jobId: jobId},
        success: function(data1) {
            data1 = data1;
            finished();
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
            alert(errorThrown);
        }
    });
```

Comment: lol cool analogy, got it, could you give me an example of what that would look like in code please? thanks in advance.

Comment: I edited my code to show what I have now, but I'm getting undefined for both data and data1 everytime I do the mouseenter event. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Where did you check `data` and `data1`? It needs to be inside of the `if` statement inside of `finished()`

Comment: yeh thats where i used it, I edited the code the previous code so you can have a look. If I log it from inside the ajax request, I get the correct result but when it gets to the finished function I get undefined.

Comment: Using `$.when` is much better..details in madalin ivascu answer

Comment: @PatrickTraile Just to see if it works, try saying `window.data = undefined; window.data1 = undefined;` instead of `var data;...`

Comment: @Howzieky I will give it a shot will let you know if it works. Thanks again.